Why is the Croatian name for Ancona "Jakin", rather than something like *Jukin?
Vulgar Latin -an- is usually borrowed as a nasal 'o' into Old Croatian, which gives 'u' in Modern Croatian.
An example of that is the town name Supetar, coming from an ancient name such as *Sanpetrus (Saint Peter). Or Sukošan, from an ancient name such as *Sancassianus (after Saint Cassianus). Or Sutivan (after Saint John, from *Santiohannes). Or Sustipan (afer Saint Stephen, from *Sanstephanus). Or the mountain name Fruška Gora, named after the Germanic tribe called Franks.
But why does the An- in Ancona appear to have been borrowed as a long 'a', rather than nasal 'o'? Why is the Croatian name for Ancona "Jakin", rather than something like *Jukin?

Why the downvotes, actually?
